# Remove "all products tab" in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my template there is a "All" tab, where you can get all products.

I want to remove and set by default other tab.

How can achieve this? The tab is no configurable under the admin panel, so what file do I need to modify?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more information, it is unclear what you are referring to and thus there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: check out the "TODO" link ("All" in spanish) in the web: https://www.victoriarockera.com

Comment: Well that helps clarify, but I don't have the answer because this is a specific customization for your theme (a theme I'm not personally familiar with). Possibly you need to modify `front-page.php` or `index.php`.

Comment: thank you @helgatheviking I'll check :)